# Breakpoints does not point to the actual code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, doxygen, breakpoints

Does anyone have a clue what could cause a breakpoint not to show the actual place of the code in a specific file?

This is the second time this has happened to me.. maybe someone could help, my parameters:

I am working in visual studio 2010.

This one specifically is a static lib but it also happened to me inside dll's.

The PDB's are generated in Z7, although this has also happened to me in the default pdb generation.

I am sure the code is compiled with the correct lib(also happened in dlls so..)

Also I have some Doxygen comments I first suspected causing this problem(could it be?)

- Attached is an image that show where the breakpoint arrow is compared to the callstack of where it ACTUALLY is..

Thanks!
[image: Bad debugging]

Comment: Does this error go away after a recompilation? Because sometimes the files just get out of sync and recompilation/rebuild fixes the problem.

Comment: No, it does not, many many rebuilds

Comment: Clean the whole project, rebuild from scratch and try again.

Comment: Did, still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently the visual studio text editor doesn't adapt well to CR..
I found that the file had some CR (and not CRLF) and that confused the compiler all together..
When I actually made a compile error on purpose, it didn't even point to the correct line...

So I added LineFeeds(LF) after every CR and it compiles fine... 
(Used notepad++ to detect where it was missing but I'm sure VS has a way as well..)
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you debug code that has optimization enabled, the method might just be inlined. This is at least one proven source of breakpoints not pointing to the right position.

Answer (score 0):

One of the scenario's which I have generally noticed is when source file changes due to fetch of a file from source control while debugging. Break point uses the line number of older code.

Comment: It did not change, also my settings does not allow unsynchronized code (if the source files do not match, then no breakpoints at all)